# EditText width parameter fill_parent does not fill width of parent container?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my xml layout file all of EditText Views do not fill the width of the parent container? They are contained within a relative layout file and I use a fragment to inflate the view. 
For some strange reason Eclipse shows the layout file with the correct view but the emulator does not.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dip"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/NameEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/NameTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/NameTextView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/GenderSpinner"

        android:ems="10" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/GenderTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/NameTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/NameTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dip"
        android:text="Gender" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/GenderSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/NameEditText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/GenderTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/GenderTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HeighttextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/GenderTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/GenderTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dip"
        android:text="Height" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/HeighteditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/HeighttextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/HeighttextView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/GenderSpinner"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:hint="eg:5'11">

    </EditText>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/WeightTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/HeighttextView"

        android:layout_below="@+id/HeighttextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Weight" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/WeighteditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/WeightTextView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/GenderSpinner"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/WeightTextView"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="lbs." >


    </EditText>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LoginIdTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/WeightTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/WeightTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dip"
        android:text="Login Id" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/LoginditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/LoginIdTextView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/GenderSpinner"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LoginIdTextView"
        android:ems="10"
         >


    </EditText>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PasswordTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LoginIdTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LoginIdTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dip"
        android:text="Password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/PasswordEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/PasswordTextView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/GenderSpinner"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/PasswordTextView"
        android:ems="10"
         >


    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Relative aligns are probably your problem. Why don't you use linear layout instead?

Comment: Nested Linear Layout?

Comment: Yes, 6 horizontal linear layouts. Relative Layout will cause more controls and i don't recommend it if you don't need specific design. It seems that your form is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Can I also use table layout?